# How to tell if two dates in a list are consecutive in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have sorted a list of string dates by order

```
sorteddates =['2017-04-26', '2017-05-05', '2017-05-10', '2017-05-11', '2017-05-16']
```

I have tried using this to sort my code by consecutive dates by I am having a difficult time understanding. I want to see if which 2 dates are consecutive. Only two dates.

```
dates = [datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d") for d in sorteddates]
date_ints = set([d.toordinal() for d in dates])
```

Comment: You won't get that if you convert to a `set` because the ordering will be screwed

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. That was an example I found on another question but it doesn't make sense here. Do I just compare each value back to back? I want to be efficient but I know changing months will mess things up.

Comment: I'm kinda not sure if I understand the question. Do they have to be consecutive dates in the list, or just pairs of dates within the set?

Comment: They have to be consecutive. I need to return the 2 dates. Like '2017-05-10', '2017-05-11'. It could be a tuple. I do not mind. I've never used datetime which is my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, to get first pair of consecutive dates you can check if their delta is 1 day:

```
from datetime import datetime

sorteddates =['2017-04-26', '2017-05-05', '2017-05-10', '2017-05-11', '2017-05-16']
dates = [datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d") for d in sorteddates]

d = next(((d1, d2) for d1, d2 in zip(dates, dates[1:]) if (d2 - d1).days == 1), None )  # <-- returns pair or None if no consecutive dates are found

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
(datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 11, 0, 0))
```

---

Or formatted:

```
if d:
    print([datetime.strftime(i, "%Y-%m-%d") for i in d])
```

Prints:

```
['2017-05-10', '2017-05-11']
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert the list from str to `datetime` -- still in sorted order.
2. Iterate through the list; for each item, check to see whether the next item is one day later -- `datetime` has `timedelta` values as well.

Some code:

```
# Convert list to datetime; you've shown you can do that part.
enter code here
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
for today, tomorrow in zip(sorteddates, sorteddates[1:]):
    if today + one_day == tomorrow:
        print ("SUCCESS")
```

Comment: Might be more helpful to print the consecutive dates with `print ('{}, {}'.format(today, tomorrow))`

Comment: @d_kennetz: since OP didn't specify how the "hit" would be used, I kept the identification trivial.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the vote of confidence.  OP got a solution, I got some reputation, and two of you are watching my back with good comments.  Win.

Comment: I have gotten into a decent practice of looking at other answers and comparing votes to see if a solution that was not the accepted answer may better fit my use case. Hopefully future visitors to this question will do the same!